# BigTiff no longer supported after upgrade to python 3 / gdal 2.3.3

Tags: python, gdal

I recently upgraded to python 3 using Anaconda and found there is a problem when trying to load bigtiff files.

ERROR 4: This is a BigTIFF file.  BigTIFF is not supported by this version of GDAL and libtiff.

Below is the code that generates the error:

```
gdalobj = gdal.Open(path\to\bigtiff\file)
```

Opening small tif files works. I'm using Windows 10, 64 bit, python 3.7.4, gdal 2.3.3, libtiff 4.0.10. I have tried upgrading gdal using conda, conda-forge, and pip as suggested by previous posts with similar problems. Either nothing changes or errors occur during the upgrade. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a newer version of gdal from conda or conda-forge? Like 2.4.1 or 3.0.4?

If that doesn't work you can try installing a .whl file from this page (where it is already built, unlike pip):

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal

This page doesn't have 2.3.3 butit has 2.4.1 instead, make sure to install the amd64 version if you have a 64bit SO (`Windows Key + Pause` to check).

Install it from inside your enviroment using this command:

```
pip install C:/dir/to/file/location/gdal-2.4.1.whl
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Parrawk. I have tried your suggestions but still have not had success. When I try installing gdal 2.4.1 or 3.0.4 using conda-forge, I get a message that says 'Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.' It then goes through an extremely long process to look for incompatabilities and ends with an error.

Comment: I also tried downloading the .whl file as suggested and installing with pip. The installation was successful but my code still did not run, this time ending with an error saying 'Can't load requested DLL...'

Comment: Have you tried making a new enviroment? I have gdal 3.0.4 installed with libtiff 4.1 and Python 3.7.6 on Windows 8.1. So we have similar setups. I don't know what conflicts conda is trying to resolve. Try moving to Python 3.7.6 if you can in a new enviroment and see if that helps.
And editing your post with your errors may help someone find the problem.

Comment: Also, install everything you need from conda first, and then use pip to install whatever you need from pip, in my case I used conda to install most packages and had no issues. And I only installed mpi4py on pip last.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Parrawk's suggestions, I created a new conda environment that uses python 3.7.6 (the default installation with Anaconda3 was 3.7.4). From within this env, I ran conda install gdal, which installed gdal 3.0.2. After a few additional installations (matplotlib, statsmodels, etc.) my code worked as expected!